# no route matches [GET] error for css files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I got the following error when running rails server:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/scaffold.css")
```

Here is development.rb file:

```
Depot::Application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false

# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true

end
```

routes.rb file:

```
Depot::Application.routes.draw do
get "store/index"

resources :products    
root :to => 'store#index', :as => 'store'
end
```

I tried putting in "config.serve_static_assets = true" but it does not help. Does anyone know what is wrong ?

Comment: I have post the routes.rb file

Answer (score 2):

You've probably got a messed up route somewhere, or you have a controller called `assets_controller` or something else that is causing a naming conflict with the path `/assets/scaffold.css` Essentially the error is telling you that `/assets/scaffold.css` is being interpreted as `/controller/action.format` - meaning...

It thinks `assets_controller` exists, and you're trying to call the `scaffold` action, requesting a response in `.css` format.

Also, make sure your `scaffold.css` file, per this path, is in `%APP_ROOT%/public/assets/scaffold.css`